# Adding in SearchController causes Navigation Bar to be black

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am adding in a UISearchController in my navigation controller and when I do, the entire navigation bar goes black, instead of the color I want. It does go to the desired color when the I click on the search bar however.

[Before calling setupSearch()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hmVg.png)

[After calling setupSearch()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBqw9.png)

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate()
        create()
        setupNav()
        setupSearch()
    }

    func delegate() {
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func create() {
        definesPresentationContext = true
        view.backgroundColor = .backgroundColor()
    }

    func setupNav() {
        guard let navController = navigationController else { return }
        navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .secondaryColor()
        navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Browse"
        navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.customHeaderFont(size: 23), .foregroundColor: UIColor.textColor()]
    }

    func setupSearch() {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

        searchController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your emulator run on Dark Mode?

Answer (score 2):

if you give color to `barTintColor` and set `isTranslucent` to `false`，setting `navigationItem.searchController` will cause the bar to turn black

[image]

Solution 1, if you want to always display the searchbar

```
 navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

Solution 2， set navigationController backgroundColor

```
  navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .red
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color of the `View` (outermost) that contains the `safeArea`, that works for me. The reason that you are seeing a black color is that you did not assign any color to the View background so the default one is assigned